# How to add a table to an email with the build result?

Tags: jenkins, postman, jenkins-mailer-plugin

I have a problem.
In Jenkins, I run automatic tests using Postman. When the build is done, an e-mail notification is sent with an attachment with the logs. In Jenkins, Newman returns me a table with the results:

I would like only such a table with the result to be in the e-mail.
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9lmh.png)

Comment: Related: [Postman: Configure Jenkins to automatically send emails containing test reports](https://blog.600mb.com/a?ID=01650-dcb5f847-8c6f-4795-869a-25a46af9743e)

Comment: @ArunKumarB

finally in the mail: T

Test report
ERROR: File 'Report path' does not exist